# Did the Algol 68 standard allow a procedure to be called before its declaration?

Tags: programming, algol

In Algol 68, is it legal to say this?

```
proc even = (int x) bool: (x = 0 | true | odd(x – 1));

proc odd = (int x) bool: (x = 0 | false | even(x – 1));
```

Forward references in structures are used in the [Revised Report](https://jmvdveer.home.xs4all.nl/en.post.algol-68-revised-report.html) (10.3.5), but this works because, I think, the syntax “expands” the right-hand side of a **mode-declaration** when the mode's name is applied, not when it is declared.

However, neither the report nor Lindsey and van der Meulen's [*Informal Introduction*](https://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/ALGOL/book/Lindsey_van_der_Meulen-IItA68-Revised.pdf) mention or use forward references of procedures (as far as I can tell). The way the syntax works doesn't seem to allow “delaying” the parsing of a **routine-text**, so I don't see how it could permit referring to something before it's declared.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138205/discussion-on-question-by-texdr-aft-did-the-algol-68-standard-allow-a-procedure).

Answer (score 8):

[RosettaCode](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Mutual_recursion#ALGOL_68) provides the following example of mutually-recursive procedures in Algol-68:

```
PROC (INT)INT m; # ONLY required for ELLA ALGOL 68RS - an official subset OF full ALGOL 68 #
 
PROC f = (INT n)INT:
  IF n = 0 THEN 1
  ELSE n - m(f(n-1)) FI;
 
m := (INT n)INT:
  IF n = 0 THEN 0
  ELSE n - f(m(n-1)) FI;
 
main:
(
  FOR i FROM 0 TO 19 DO
    print(whole(f(i),-3))
  OD;
  new line(stand out);
  FOR i FROM 0 TO 19 DO
    print(whole(m(i),-3))
  OD;
  new line(stand out)
)
```

That is, the standard did not require a forward-declaration, but some implementation did for convenience of the implementor.

In the *Informal introduction*, we read

> 4.2.2.3. Recursion
>
> Suppose, now, that a routine happens to contain a call on itself (either
> directly, or via a chain of calls on other routines which eventually calls the same one again). Are there any problems? In some programming languages
> there may be, but not in this one. It all works out normally, just like you
> would expect.

And later, in Appendix 4.3,

> The following restrictions arise because of the requirement for one-pass
> compilation:
> All declarations of indicators (i.e. of identifiers, operators and mode indications) must precede the first applied occurrences (3.2.3) which
> identify them. This is normally good programming practice anyway
> (moreover, see 3.2.3.E7) and the only case where you might regret the
> restriction is that of mutually recursive pairs of procedures (you would
> have to declare one of them as a proc variable in the sublanguage)...

Therefore, the standard did indeed allow referring to routines which are not yet declared, in *routine-texts*, when using a full compiler, and a restriction that declarations must precede occurrences is specific to one-pass compilers.

Comment: I read that as saying “you need to declare procedures before calling them in standard Algol 68”

Comment: @texdr.aft Please follow the link for the full context of that "ONLY required" comment.

Comment: @texdr.aft - all of Appendix 4 is specifically about the (standard) sublanguage Algol 68S.

Comment: The declaration `PROC (INT) INT m;` is not actually a forward declaration. It is a complete declaration of a variable of mode REF PROC, to which a routine is later assigned. The equivalent in C would be `int (*m)(int);` and not `int m(int);`.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the point of including the example in this answer. The question is not about mutual recursion (which can be achieved by use of REF PROC variables, even in the sublanguage, as in the example) but of use before declaration, which the example does not show.

Comment: @another-dave The comment clearly states that the REF PROC variable declaration is not necessary for a standard-conforming compiler, but only for a compiler targeting a language subset.

Comment: If you omit that declaration, the code is invalid in Algol68 (no declaration of 'm').  It then requires a different declaration -- an identity-declaration for 'm', in place of the assignation -- which is not shown.  That is, the example demonstrates only the workaround of using a ref-to-proc; it implies but does not show the case where the workaround is not required.

Comment: @another-dave That is true, and in that sense the comment is a little misleading. That does not change the answer as a whole, though.

Answer (score 6):

Not an answer, but note that Algol 60 allowed use before declaration. I take this as a strong hint that Algol 68 would also do so.

I ran this code on the KDF9 Whetstone Algol system.

```
'begin'

'boolean' 'procedure' odd(n);
  'value' n; 'integer' n;
  'begin'
    odd := 'if' n = 0 'then' 'false' 'else' even(n-1)
  'end';

'boolean' 'procedure' even(n);
  'value' n; 'integer' n;
  'begin'
    even := 'if' n = 0 'then' 'true' 'else' odd(n-1)
  'end';

write boolean(30, odd(3))

'end'
```

This just validates that the scope of an identifier is the entire block in which it is declared (and any nested blocks, of course).

Comment: What is the significance of `30` in the `write boolean` call?

Comment: @texdr.aft - it's a semi-virtual ['device number'](http://sw.ccs.bcs.org/KDF9/AUM/page03001.jpg). 3n mapped to the line printer, although on the multi-access system Eldon2, and in the modern emulator, it is treated as console output.  I call it semi-virtual since as far as I recall, you could have multiple 3n streams that would be separately spooled to the line printer, though maybe not under Eldon.

Comment: The I/O routines are not a feature of Algol 60; every implementor did his own thing.

Answer (score 4):

I am by no means knowledgeable about Algol 68 - but that won't stop me.  I wonder if the issue is a misunderstanding of "elaboration" when an Algol 68 program runs vs. how that is represented by a w-Grammar.  In particular, I'm keying off your sentence:

> The way the syntax works doesn't seem to allow “delaying” the parsing of a **routine-text**.

These two paragraphs are from "A Practical Guide To Algol 68" (Frank G. Pagan, 1976), page 101, in a section on "Procedures Without Parameters":

[image]

[image]

To me these sentences make it clear that a procedure declaration comes into effect when it is *elaborated* (i.e., it is reached in program flow terms) and then you can *use* it.  The reference to "global identifiers which appear in a routine text" refers to both routines and "ordinary" (other) identifiers here, as this whole discussion is about a declaration of a routine which is just like declarations of other things: in this case a unit is given a `proc` name.

I don't know how this translates to the two-level grammar, but I think perhaps that considering the grammar as about *generating* valid Algol 68 programs as opposed to *recognizing* valid Algol 68 programs may help ...

**Update:** Check out the great article ["A History Of ALGOL 68" (Lindsey, 1996)](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/234286.1057810) - easy to read (though long), and nicely chatty (even gossipy!).  If you scroll down to page 38 of the PDF (page number 64 in the document) he has a very useful comparison of the W-grammar syntax to *PROLOG*!  And points out the backtracking of PROLOG!  And this might be the way to get to understanding how the grammar can define valid programs where all the identifiers are properly declared - even *after* being mentioned in text.  See the discussion of "blind alleys", which is more extensive in the next section `2.5.1.2` *Predicates*. And *that* takes you to `2.5.1.3` *Context Conditions vs NESTs* which is where your question about how this works *in the grammar* is (i.e., might be?) finally answered. With the caveat that

> The tools required to do this are still complex, but once one has
> understood them they hardly intrude. And their formality ensures that it is always possible to work
> through any particular case and to see whether and why it is or is not allowed.

Or so he says. A bit later describing the way in which "infinite modes" are *removed* from the language he says

> It is, admittedly, also hard work to read (in spite of copious
> pragmatics), but the Report is written so that it does not obtrude, and the naive reader need hardly be
> aware of it.

So it is clear that one approach, suggested by one of the main language designers, is to declare yourself resolutely naive and thus, with respect to all this complexity, you need hardly be aware of it!  What a relief!

Comment: I agree, but that skates over the 'how'.   In the example, suppose we have  `z := f` rather than `z := 3`.  We may not know the mode of `f` when encountering this.  Obviously a multi-pass compiler can figure it out...

Comment: I'm not sure that a grammar (expressed in any formalism) could generate a valid forward reference without keeping track of the as-yet undeclared identifiers. The unrestricted nature of w-grammars would make this possible, but I don't think the Algol 68 revised report does it.

Comment: @another-dave - the question is about the Algol-68 grammar specified in the "Revised Report".  The motivation for the grammar, described in `1. Language and metalanguage` / `1.1 The method of description` /  `1.1.1 Introduction` (and other commentary on the Algol 68 report) makes it clear that the grammar is a _generator_ of a language - in particular, it generates all valid production trees and assigns a meaning to each such tree.  The OP is asking for "how" the grammar allows mutual references.  That's a _different_ "how" than _your_ "how" which is how a compiler can use (or not use) the ...

Comment: ... grammar to _parse_ a valid string in the "representation language".  (Remember, grammars can be used to _generate_ as well as _recognize_ (i.e., "parse") - any may be more suited for one purpose than the other, depending on your tooling - in particular - nobody at all would attempt to _parse_ a language using a two-level grammar.) And I readily admit my answer doesn't answer _either_ "how" - as my last sentence states.

Comment: @davidbak - Hmm, somewhere along the line I got the idea that Lindsey's compiler was driven by the grammar.  But this is not my field; I (a rude mechanical) use the tools, I don't write 'em.  Thanks.

Comment: @another-dave - amazing idea to me and now I'll go digging on that - I'd love to find out more.

Comment: @another-dave - check this out: [A History Of ALGOL 68 (Lindsey, 1996)](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/234286.1057810) - it's super informative while being chatty (not to mention gossipy).  Anyway, look down to page 39 where Lindsey says "The Bad News is that it is quite impossible to write a parser based on unrestricted W-Grammars.  If you want to do that, you must introduce some more structure, as in Prolog, or as in the Affix Grammars described in Kostner 1971."  So I think that Lindsey's compiler was probably driven by a CFG derived from the ALGOL 68 RR grammar.

Comment: If that's from HOPL, I have it and have read it a few times.  But apparently I have suffered a single-bit error somewhere in my memory of what it said.  Time to re-read!  Thanks.  (The Bad News seems to be on p65, not p39, in that PDF)

Comment: @another-dave - it's a difference between the printed page number in the document and the actual PDF page number as shown in my pdf reader.

Answer (score 3):

[Algol 68R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALGOL_68-R) was the first Algol 68 implementation, released before the Revised Report. The "R" is because it was a restricted subset of the language, largely to allow a single-pass compiler to be written.

Among the restrictions were the requirement for all identifiers to be declared ("specified" in Algol jargon) before use. It would seem, thereby, that full Algol 68 did not impose this requirement. Your example, in slightly improved form,

```
PROC even = (INT number) BOOL: ( number = 0 | TRUE | odd (ABS (number - 1)));
PROC odd = (INT number) BOOL: ( number = 0 | FALSE | even (ABS (number - 1)));
```

Needs to be re-written for Algol 68R as:

```
PROC (INT) BOOL odd;
PROC even = (INT number) BOOL : ( number = 0 | TRUE | odd (ABS (number - 1)));
odd := (INT number) BOOL : ( number = 0 | FALSE | even (ABS (number - 1)));
```

To allow mutually recursive declarations of types ("modes") in 68R, the `MODE` keyword must be used to create "stub" declarations:

```
MODE B;
MODE A = STRUCT (REF B b);
MODE B = [1:10] REF A;
```

I did a fair amount of programming in 68R at college in 1981-83, and the need for forward declarations was not a significant problem.

Comment: It's too bad specifications for more languages don't recognize the value of limited-subset implementations, with a proviso that a conforming limited-subset implementation may reject constructs that would be difficult to support, but *must correctly support constructs it does not reject*.  C would have been a much more useful language for 8-bit computers if features like recursion weren't seen as mandatory.  On a 6502, incrementing a statically-allocated 8-bit value stored would take 2 or 3 bytes of code, and 5 or 6 cycles.  Using an automatic-duration object in a re-entrant function...

Comment: ...would increase the typical cost to 9 bytes of code with an execution time of 17 cycles.  While it's possible for a 6502 C implementations to generate code that supports recursion, having it supported without regard for whether programs need it is a gross violation of the "only pay for what you use" principle.

Comment: As you said, the restrictions of Algol-68R were mostly needed to permit a one-pass compiler. Those particular restrictions (but not all others) ended up in the sublanguage of the *Revised Report*.

Comment: But I think the "R" in Algol-68R is for "RSRE" (Royal Signals and Radar Establishment), not "Restricted".  See other contemporary examples, such as -68C, for "Cambridge".

Comment: Incidentally: Kernighan & Ritchie's book on C, at 228 pages (original paperback) has been considered an example of concision in the genre. The ALGOL 68-R User's Guide by Woodward & Bond, which is pitched at the same level of audience, weighs in at 99 pages.  And they say ALGOL 68 was "complicated"  :-)

Comment: @another-dave: How about the 1974 C Reference Manual?  The present Standard is many times as long, but the language hasn't improved nearly enough to justify the expansion.  Indeed, many aspects of the language are less well specified than they were in the original 1974 text.